# How To Avoid Repair With Keycache?

Tags: mysql

I have had some experience with optimizing the my.cnf file but my database has around 4 million records (MyISAM).  I am trying to restore from a mysqldump but every time I do I eventually get the dreaded "Repair With Keycache", that may take days. Is there any way to get past this and let it roll as "Repair By Sorting"?

I have 2GB RAM, Dual Cores, lots of extra hard-drive space.

Snip out of my.cnf:

```
set-variable = max_connections=650
set-variable = key_buffer=256M
set-variable = myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
set-variable = join_buffer=1M
set-variable = record_buffer=1M
set-variable = sort_buffer_size=2M
set-variable = read_buffer_size=2M
set-variable = query_cache_size=32M
set-variable = table_cache=1024
set-variable = thread_cache_size=256
set-variable = wait_timeout=7200
set-variable = connect_timeout=10
set-variable = max_allowed_packet=16M
set-variable = max_connect_errors=10
set-variable = thread_concurrency=8
```

Comment: You should accept MarkR's answer.

Comment: Marc Gear's answer should be the one accepted, since disk space is usually not a problem while `myisam_max_sort_file_size` set to a low value is more likely to occur

Answer (score 37):

"Repair by sorting" uses the filesort routine, which in turn creates several temporary files (usually) in your tmpdir.

If your tmpdir does not have enough space for them, it will revert to "Repair by keycache". This is extremely bad as it's much slower AND creates less optimal indexes.

There are some other conditions but I haven't identified them.

Working out the size of tmpdir you need for filesort() is nontrivial; the format data are stored in the filesort buffer is not the same as MYD files, it typically uses a lot more space.

So if your tmpdir points at a small /tmp (or tmpfs), you might want to change it to a larger /var/tmp - if that exists.

Comment: Most important condition - myisam_max_sort_file_size variable. I'm has enough free disk space, but always run 'Repair by keycache', and only when set myisam_max_sort_file_size to 10G, get a 'Repair by sort', which is four to five times faster then 'Repair by keycache' on my data. Thnx to @Marc-Gear

Comment: Switching the tmpdir to a different partition worked for me. Took an index creation on a large table (~800 million rows) from 2.5 days to 2.5 hours.

Answer (score 19):

MySQL will use repair by keycache for MyISAM tables whenever the maximum possible size of the tables indexes are greater than the value for the variable myisam_max_sort_file_size.

You can calculate the maximum size of the index by adding up the byte size values for all keys in all the indexes and multiplying that by the number of rows in your table.

Increase the myisam_max_sort_file_size and your index will be rebuilt using sorting on disk, rather than with the slow keycache method.

Comment: I'm using RHEL5 w/ MySQL w/ minor tweaks of my.cnf, importing of one db takes 15h, importing same db to CentOS5 (on much newer machine w/ different my.cnf) takes about 1.5h, I'm going try your myisam_max_sort_file_size as now it set to 2G, and my table is 5G, I do have planty of space... I can't wait to try it out!

Comment: I just set myisam_max_sort_file_size to 8G in my my.cnf, yet I still seeing "Repair with keycache" my "tmpdir" points to /tmp folder, which has about 90G free space, I don't really see mysqld using it at all... any ideas why? I checked permissions everything looks Ok.

Comment: How many rows does your table have? and indexes does it have (over what size rows). To rebuild 4 Gb table, I needed it set to about 15gb (it didn't use anywhere near this much)

Comment: It seems that if you have a column that is if type utf8, then mysql assumes each character to occupy 4-bytes instead of 1. So, even if your table is say 1GiB, and you have 1 column of that type, MySQL might actually think it needs to reserve 4 GiB instead of 1 GiB, which sounds a bit wasteful to me.

Answer (score 10):

I accidentially ran a repair table quick on a new database which I had not set up to be fast reg. myisam_max_sort_file_size which was way too small compared to the .MID file (which is 88279393280 byes large, about 88GB). The data file is 85GB. The table is 1.2 billion records, consisting of an ID, two dates, a tinytext ,a few bigints and a double. My server (2GB virtual linux running in a box under windows7) only have one core of the 4 on the windows server, but it is running 3+ GHZ. I was fearing this "repair by keycache" event would take forever - given horror stories with far smaller tables.

Fortunately it "only" took 1 day , 10 hours and 20.72 seconds to complete the repair table quick operation.

What I miss the most is some way of knowing how far into the operation that mysql is, and how soon it might be finished. This is still unknown to me.

I have now changed my my.ini file and double checked with df that I have ample disk space for those large temporary files.

Anyway.. my main point, which might be very useful knowledge to the next guy who falls into this trap.. is in fact... don't panic! it might be slow, but it is possible on rather sub-par hardware to get 1+ billion records sorted out within a day or two. Got three indexes, one on a date field, one on a bigint field, and one primary on the ID field.

I would've posted this as a comment to one of the solutions, but I can't seem to figure how to do this, with the user interface here, so I'll drop it off as a solution. Don't upvote me, it's just a note that I would have loved to have here, I was almost going to kill my "sort by keycache" thread as I thought it could take a week or more. 2 days per billion records is manageable..

Edit: And now, a repair table on the same database, but with a large enough mysiam_max_sort_file_size setting took 10 hours, 20 minutes using repair by sorting. The most diskspace used was about 250GB, but i had set myisam_max_sort_file_size a lot higher, reflecting how much disk space is actually free on the server.

Tracking progress is hard. Disk space went up and down while the individual indexes were built, but there were hour long pauses where no changes were made reg. disk space usage (as reported by df).

Comment: I have table of 4 billion rows and it would not repair by keycache after a month. It was impossible. It depends on the number and complexity of the indexes; a large table with only a primary key will build very quickly even with keycache, but not if you have 7 multi-column indexes.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Mark, Yes that is exactly what I ended up trying and am seeing from the logs that that's the reason it switched to "Repair with keycache", was an out of space error.

This is what I did to get my solution in place as I will not go through the fact that it was pointing to `/tmp/mysqltmp/`, which only had a max of 2MB.

**So I did this:**

```
mkdir /home/mysqltmp

chown mysql:mysql /home/mysqltmp
```

**changed my tmp dir in my.conf to** `tmpdir=/home/mysqltmp/`

Now if I use `df -h /home/mysqltmp`, what I see is that dir has 285 GB available, so that really was a nice sight to see, had plenty of free space, plus I could see mysql was wanting 20GB easily.  So what was taking me 12 hours before now is complete in 20 minutes, that is over 3 million records insert to index.

Comment: One thing don't forget to restart mysql after you change my.conf, this is how I do a mysql restart in Apache RedHat: service mysqld restart

Comment: This should be an update on your question, rather than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions here worked for me: no matter how much I increased the `myisam_sort_buffer_size` variable or where I made the `tmpdir` variable point to, the table always got repaired with keycache.

What worked was to use the commandline utility `myisamchk`:

```
myisamchk --sort-recover --sort_buffer_size=14G /path/to/table
```

where:

- `/path/to/table` is the path of the database file without its extension (so, without the `.MYI` at the end). It is by default located in directory `/var/lib/mysql/your_database`.
- Change the buffer size from `14G` to whatever free space available you have.

As an added bonus, it also displays the on-going progress as it churns the data.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MySQL Reference Manual, disk space must be available "*in the file system containing the directory where the original index file is located*" (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_myisam_max_sort_file_size) -- this applies to (at least) v5.0 and above. This contradicts some of the above answers, that claim that increasing the disk space for the tmp directory would help.

I can confirm the behaviour described in the Reference Manual: temporary disk space is used where the table's data (`*.MYD`) & index files (`*.MYI`) are stored, but not in `tmpdir`.