# MySQL Repair with keycache following INSERT FROM SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not an expert with MySQL, and I am trying to understand why the table shows Repair with Keycache and what I can do to correct it at this point. I have done some searching, but haven't been able to find much on this particular cause...

The situation: I have a table of 36 million records. As part of an optimization process, I wanted to remove one of the indexes, specifically a UNIQUE index, from tablea. To do so, I created a new table (CREATE TABLE tableb LIKE tablea) and removed the unique index from tableb (DROP INDEX unique FROM tableb). Finally, I copied the information from tablea into tableb (INSERT INTO tableb SELECT * FROM tablea). For about four hours, the status was Sending Data, then it changed to Repairing from Keycache.

My understanding was that when doing an INSERT from SELECT, the indexes are built as the data is being copied, which is why I didn't simply drop the index from the existing table, which I believe involves refactoring all of the surviving indexes. Was there something wrong in my approach, or is this normal?

Finally, now that it is doing the Repair from keycache, is there anything I can do? Can I kill the process and do a repair or change the settings, or do I need to wait for the repair process to complete?

Last log entries if they help:

```
101229 14:28:28 [Warning] Warning: Enabling keys got errno 137 on db.#sql-19cc_3243, retrying
101229 16:04:02 [Warning] Warning: Enabling keys got errno 137 on db.tableb, retrying
```

Comment: I'm also having this same issue. It's quite weird that a non-damaged table goes into Repair with keycache after adding/dropping an index. It looks like mysql damaged the table in the process and now it's doing a repair..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out the answers under this question: [MySQL - How To Avoid Repair With Keycache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067367/mysql-how-to-avoid-repair-with-keycache)

Comment: I have read through that. I already have MySQL using a large tmp directory (250Gb) and I am not sure how to estimate a viable size to increase myisam_max_sort_file_size to to be sure that isn't the problem. Also, is it safe to stop the process to change that setting?

Comment: According to Ingo Strüwing[1]: "The theoretical maximum index size for normal indexes is maximum field length (times character width where appropriate, 3 for UTF8) plus 1 for max lengths below 256, 2 otherwise, plus the myisam_data_pointer_size, times the current number of records in the table. For full text indexes the maximum word length (31) (times character width) is added to the key length."

[1]http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,86150,86992#msg-86992

Comment: As for it being "safe" to stop the process, I'm not sure. According to your question, this is a copy of the original table that you're working on. If the original table is still there for use while you figure out all the optimizations on the new table, why not just drop the new table and start over on it?