# MYSQL myisam Repair with keycache

Tags: mysql, myisam

I'm disabling keys; bulk load data; and then re build the index on a myisam table.  however, 
the last part takes forever because it is

```
Repair with keycache
```

instead of repair by sort
here are my variables,  I have about 100 million records in the table, each row has one integer primary key, one smallint column, and one varchar(256) column.  my myisam_max_sort_file_size is 500G, I doubt that the thereotical max size of the indices will be anywhere close to that.

```
mysql> show variables where variable_name like '%myisam%';
+---------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name             | Value                |
+---------------------------+----------------------+
| myisam_data_pointer_size  | 6                    |
| myisam_max_sort_file_size | 536870912000         |
| myisam_mmap_size          | 18446744073709551615 |
| myisam_recover_options    | OFF                  |
| myisam_repair_threads     | 1                    |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size   | 4294967296           |
| myisam_stats_method       | nulls_unequal        |
| myisam_use_mmap           | OFF                  |
+---------------------------+----------------------+
```

my box has 8 GB of RAM and 250GB of storage,  why doesn't MYSQL use repair with sort?

Comment: Possible dupe. See MarkR's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067367/mysql-how-to-avoid-repair-with-keycache

Comment: I have read the other thread, it didn't help me.  I have enough disk space in /tmp which is what my mysql is using

Comment: How big is the table? If you increase the size of myisam_sort_buffer_size it might help.

Comment: the table has 100 million rows, but I set the myisam_sort_buffer_size to 4G. myisam_max_sort_file_size is 500G which should be large enough

Comment: apparently myisam_sort_buffer_size = 4G is not enough, I needed to set it to 10G, then enable keys will use repair with sort.  It baffles me!

Comment: which version of mysql where you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apparently myisam_sort_buffer_size = 4G is not enough, I needed to set it to 10G, then enable keys will use repair with sort. It baffles me!

Comment: isn't myisam_sort_buffer_size written to memory? setting it to 10G when you have 8G of ram, how dose that work?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else finding this, I discovered recently my `MySQL 5.1` server does not like `myisam_sort_buffer_size` to be an exact multiple of `4G`. I discovered this after a major RAM upgrade leaving me with Repair from Keycache.

I tested a `200MB` table `ENABLE KEYS` with different values for myisam_sort_buffer_size

```
4G - repair with keycache
5G - repair with sort
6G - repair with sort
7G - repair with sort
8G - repair with keycache
```

...

Not sure if the 4G multiple was specific to my config, but its something to look out for. Took me a long time to discover that after trying setting to `8G`, `16G`, even `64GB`.